# packing / merging 2 exe files

Tags: cmd

hello is it possible to merge / combine / pack two .exe files

example :

1.exe + 2.exe = 3.exe

and how to run one of them, then another, like : start 3.exe:2.exe...

thanks

Comment: What do you want to do? Run simultaneously (start 1st then 2nd) or in sequence?

Comment: yes i want to run them simultaneously, but if is possible id like to run the second exe using first exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, by `cmd` command:

- Type `notepad text1.txt`: this creates a new notepad file and you can type anything inside, save it then close.
- Type `notepad text1.txt:hidden.txt`: you can type anything and save it. This means `hidden.txt` become inside `text1.txt` but you can not see it. Why? Long story :) These are about NTFS issues.

Also you can do it for `.exe` files.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason to not having a batch script? There are utilities to convert the .bat file to either .com or .exe if this is required for "obfuscating" the .bat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Installer (e.g. from WISE and many others) to do that.